# How to use HAProxy with a wordpress site?

Tags: nginx, haproxy, wordpress

I know how to setup HAProxy and get multiple backends to work together to balance the load. However, the problem remains, how to host WordPress (via nginx and MySQL) on such setup?

The problem is that if you install it in this way, you'll have multiple different backends. Say you instaleld a wordpress website on backend1, if you were redirected to backend2 and you created a new post, that post will be only in backend2, right? So we'll also need replication between the backends in order to serve the exact same content?

Am I missing something?

Comment: @gf_ Is there a way of doing it for the complete server automatically? Like, a tool which make the multiple backends always synchronized?

Comment: You seem to want an answer to the question "how do I scale Wordpress", but what you've actually asked is "how do I use HAProxy with Wordpress". Can you please clarify what you actually want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind WordPress you will have a database.  This need not be on the same server as the WordPress application, although it usually is.

You have two options:

- Use a single database for all the WordPress servers (HAProxy back-ends).
- Configure the databases to replicate across the servers.

Comment: Do note that you'll need a similar solution for file uploads - replication or some sort of shared storage.

Answer (score 1):

As BillThor said, you can have wordpress application running on multiple backend servers and still can use a common MySQL server for both of them.

For all the wp-admin traffic you can set an acl to route the traffic only one server, else it may lead to session issues.

And all the read traffic (i.e. reader's traffic) can be routed to both the backend servers either in round robin fashion or on basis of the URIs.